# Mongoose / mongoDB drop unique index constraint

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I created a unique index using Mongoose sometime ago in my database.

```
Model.index({name: 1, location: 1}, {unique: true});
```

Now due to some coding changes, I would like to drop the uniqueness on the index. Is there a way to just drop the uniqueness on the index?

The only thing I can come up with is to just do

```
Model.dropIndex({name: 1, location: 1});
Model.index({name: 1, location: 1});
```

Is this correct? Or is there less a confusing way to write the code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes as stated in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/manage-indexes/#modify-an-index):

> To modify an existing index, you need to drop and recreate the index
>   with the exception of m TTL indexes.

So your code is correct for the time being. Maybe in the future they add the possibility to change it in place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct way of dropping. You can either do it from mongo client.

or from node server like this

```
Model( { {name: 1, location: 1} }, function(err){
     if(err){
         res.send("error");
    }
    else{
        res.send("success");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a UI tool like RoboMongo, you can drop it from its UI